# convolutional neural network text classification additional features

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, text-classification

I am trying to implement CNN on text classification task. I understand that CNN can extract and abstract features from pure text.

What if I have some additional very useful features that not in the text? How should I add those features into the CNN?

Currently, what I am doing is concatenating the convolution layer results with an additional feature vector. And then feed them to the hidden layers. Is this a right way to do it?

Thanks!